# How to iterate over a pandas data frame when using the basemap function to check the result

Tags: pandas, dataframe, latitude-longitude, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to write apython script that will do a geometric transformation for the long/lat values, namely the rotation.  However, I want to resulted long/lat to preserve the location, for example if the otiginal coordinate is in the land I want the rotated one to be also in land.  Therefore, I have used **basemap** 
I wrote the following script and it works fine, till I tried to add a while loop.  My objective from adding the while loop is to compare the original value with the rotated one and if they dont match, the rotation angle will change till they match.  I will show my concept without adding the while loop first:

```
   def rotation(dfc):
    # Rotation
     choose a rotation angle that will match the location of the rotated 
     coordinates, and set the result to 1 if they match
     while row['result']=0
        choose another rotation angle
        do the rotation again
        check the result of the rotated points
        if still they dont match stay in the loop and choose another alpha
        if not break and go to the next row
```

I know it needs  simple steps, but I am not able to figure out how to add the loop for row wise functions in dataframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this problem can be solved without using df.iterrows.

I just initiated a variable to be equal 0 and then added a while loop.  So my pseudocode looks like :

```
  counter=0
  while counter != len(df['col1'])
       choose new random variable
       do the calculation using dfc.apply()
       re-calculate counter
```